# Linker error occurs while building the project from git in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, objectivezip

I have created an app that uses objective-zip 1.0.2 . And I have checked in the project to the git as well . When I download the project as a zip from the git and run and build the project , the archive gets created . But when I try to build the project from the git , I get the Following error..

```
 [exec]      [exec]     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk -L/Users/macbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mdmiosagent-alfqxkdfmyijdadbxxuldoeanaiz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/mdmiosagent/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/macbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mdmiosagent-alfqxkdfmyijdadbxxuldoeanaiz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/mdmiosagent/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/macbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mdmiosagent-alfqxkdfmyijdadbxxuldoeanaiz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/mdmiosagent/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/mdmiosagent.build/Release/mdmiosagent.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mdmiosagent.LinkFileList -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -dead_strip -ObjC -lobjective-zip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/macbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mdmiosagent-alfqxkdfmyijdadbxxuldoeanaiz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/mdmiosagent/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/mdmiosagent.build/Release/mdmiosagent.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mdmiosagent_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/macbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mdmiosagent-alfqxkdfmyijdadbxxuldoeanaiz/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/mdmiosagent/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/mdmiosagent.build/Release/mdmiosagent.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mdmiosagent
 [exec]      [exec] ld: library not found for -lobjective-zip
 [exec]      [exec] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 [exec]      [exec] 
 [exec]      [exec] ** EXPORT FAILED **
 [exec]      [exec] 
 [exec]      [exec] error: archive not found at path '/Users/macbuild/WH_DIR/Jul_26_2016/863879/MACSRC/mdmiosagent.xcarchive'
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Sounds like you have different *library search paths* in your Debug and Release Xcode build settings.

Comment: Can u explain please ?

Comment: As it's finding the library during an Archive (release configuration) and not during a normal build (debug configuration), I can only assume that's where the difference lies.

Comment: So what do you think might fix this @Droppy

Comment: Making the library searchs paths the same?

Comment: I am not able to get what u are trying to tell exactly @Droppy